# Detectar evento gerado em outra classe

Tags: c#, vb.net

Tenho uma classe (em VB) que retorna um evento de `TimeOut`, ou seja, se o tempo estourar ela retorna um evento contento com uma string com os dados que necessito usando RaiseEvent. Como posso tratar esse evento na classe principal que é em C#. Tentei utilizando delegate mas não consegui. Obrigado.

Código:

```
Public Class Dados
    Public Event _TrateTimeOut(ByVal dados As Dados)

    Private Sub MonitoraTimeOut()
        If TimeOut Is Nothing Then

            TimeOut = New Timers.Timer
            TimeOut.Interval = 10000
            AddHandler TimeOut.Elapsed, AddressOf TrateTimeOut
            TimeOut.Start()
        Else
            TimeOut.Stop()
            TimeOut.Start()
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub TrateTimeOut()
        RaiseEvent _TrateTimeOut(Me)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Você pode colocar na sua pergunta um trecho de código explicando como essa solução funciona?

Comment: Código adicionado!!

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, `_TrateTimeOut()` está declarado em algum lugar. Onde?

Comment: No início da classe Dados com:
Public Event _TrateTimeOut(ByVal dados As Dados)

Comment: Você pode adicionar ele na pergunta também, por favor?

Comment: Adicionado, vc tem uma idéia de como posso fazer ?! :)

Comment: Bom, a classe em C# precisa ter um evento com o seguinte protótipo: `private void FuncaoQueTrataOEvento(object sender, EventArgs e)`, e na inicialização você precisa instanciar `Dados` e passar a função pra dentro da classe `Dados`. Vou tentar uma resposta.

Comment: Eu tenti isso, mas o MonitoraTimeOut() não é iniciado.

Answer (score 2):

Amigo,
Nos comentários você reclama sobre o evento dentrar num loop infinito e na sua pergunta tem a seguinte passagem: "se o tempo estourar ela retorna um evento contento com uma string com os dados que necessito usando RaiseEvent"

Ele vai estourar sim, a cada 10 segundos e indefinitivamente. Mas parece que você quer seja uma vez só.

Eu usaria a versão do cigano, de forma otimizada:

`public class ConsumidorComponenteVBZao
{
    public ConsumidorComponenteVBZao() {
        var dados = new Dados();
        dados._TrateTimeOut += FuncaoQueTrataOEvento;
    }
    private void FuncaoQueTrataOEvento(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Faça aqui o tratamento de dados, e tal.
    }
}`

E no teu VBzão, usaria uma Thread e não um timer para ficar disparando eventos a cada intervalo.

Answer (score 0):

Não conheço sua classe C#, mas vou supor alguma coisa assim:

```
public class ClasseEmCSharp {
    public Dados dados = new Dados();
    public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    public ClasseEmCSharp() {
        dados._TrateTimeOut += new EventHandler(FuncaoQueTrataOEvento);
    }

    private void FuncaoQueTrataOEvento(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Faça aqui o tratamento de dados, e tal.
    }
}
```

Tá um pouco esquisito o tratamento, mas é basicamente isso.

Comment: Eu consegui em partes usando o seguinte código:
dados._TrateTimeOut += new dados._TrateTimeOutEventHandler(EncerraTimeOut);

no enentato o método que criei chamado EncerraTimeOut(), fica em um loop infinito.